# The DHCP option 58 && 59 how to work

Tags: networking, dhcp

I know 58 option specifies the time interval to RENEW state, and 59 option specifies the time interval to rebind. But I don't know whether the client should send requested option.

Should the dhcp Discover or Request packet request option 58 & 59 when client want to acquire T1 & T2 from servers?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "Does dhcp client request 58 & 59 option in Discover packet or Request packet?" mean? Can you rephrase this sentence?

Comment: @hansaplast Sorry, English is not my first language. I have changed my question. Can you understand the question this time?

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP RENEW and REBIND options are set by the DHCP server in the OFFER and in the ACK (on a REQUEST) messages. When the client specifies a lease time in the REQUEST message, the server will return properly adjusted RENEW and REBIND option values.